# Copy non blank cells to exact column and row

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to copy data from a selected range `(Y5:Z198)` to cell `(Y206)` but somehow I can only make it to `appendRow` and paste only on column A. Can someone help me, please?

```
function CopyData(CopyData) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sh1 = ss.getSheetByName("CAPA");
    var sh2 = ss.getSheetByName("CAPA");
    var rg1 = sh1.getRange("Y5:Z198");
    var vA = rg1.getValues();

    for (var i = 0; i < vA.length; i++) {
        if (vA[i][1]) {
            sh2.appendRow(vA[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want all of the data to be separated by a delimiter in Y206? It would be helpful to share a demo sheet with your current problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to copy the data

```
function CopyData(CopyData) {
  const dstRow = 206;
  let ss        = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(),
      sheet     = ss.getSheetByName('CAPA'),
      srcRange  = sheet.getRange('Y5:Z198'),
      srcValues = srcRange.getValues(),
      filtered  = srcValues.filter(item => item[1]);  // filter the data being copied
    
    // Define the range to insert
    // 'Y'+dstRow -> Y206
    // filtered.length -> the number of rows in the filtered array of data
    // ':Z'+(dstRow-1+filtered.length) -> bottom right cell

    sheet.getRange('Y'+dstRow+':Z'+(dstRow-1+filtered.length)).setValues(filtered);
}
```